# Import function that prints each row during load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of making a import funcktion (content from old system to new system). The import itself is in place - but i want the import job to print a row for each result it imports, ie.

- Imported Page 1
- Imported Page 2

The job is written in C#. What is the best way to achive the above? It is running in a web-app.

Currently it is a simple loop, like this

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in myDictionary)
{
    // Insert into DB
    // Print line that this line has been inserted into DB

}
```

The loadtime of the script is above 1 minute - there is alot of items. So to keep the user engaded, there is a need to show a status of the import, and that it is running, and how long it has gotten - a simple Print message for each entry, would do the trick.

Comment: Question is not clear, show some code...

Comment: probably print a message using c# code

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan updated the question

Comment: where do you want to print? file, console ? cant you just do Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key}: {entry.Value}"); instead of comment ?

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan It's a web-app, so no console

Comment: than you can log into file, and check ...

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan Yes, but i dont want it to log to a file only - also in the frontend :-)

Comment: Ahh, than render into html, or write SignalR hub and publish log to client,, anyway not very clear